# Was Hermione the only Gryffindor of her class in Arithmancy and Ancient Runes?

Tags: harry-potter

This was the exam schedule of third-year students in *Prisoner of Azkaban*:

> **Monday**
>
> 9 o'clock, Arithmancy
>
> 9 o'clock, Transfiguration
>
> Lunch
>
> 1 o'clock, Charms
>
> 1 o'clock, Ancient Runes
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, Chapter 16 - Professor Trelawney's Prediction</sup>

Now, both Transfiguration and Charms were core subjects. So everyone in the third year had to attend them. And Prof McGonagall told Hermione that she had to tell ministry that Hermione was extraordinary and needed that time turner badly. Her way of telling more than said it that she arranged only one time turner. Does this mean Hermione was the lone third year Gryffindor in Arithmancy and Ancient Runes?

Comment: Maybe there were multiple exams for the same subject?

Comment: Or just a catch-up exam straight away afterward for students who have a scheduling conflict, like in mundane schools

Comment: I don't see this as a dupe. This question is asking if Hermione was alone in the classes, not about the scheduling of those classes. The answers are different.

Comment: thanks @fez thats why I was annoyed when it was marked as a duplicate. It was more about Hermione and more time turners and very less about scheduling.

Comment: @fez It seems that the underlying question is that there is a scheduling conflict. Additional time turners or one-student-classes are potential resolutions to the conflict. And if, as per the answer here, they are not correct, the conflict still remains. So the question essentially reads as "Are _______ or _______ the correct resolution to this scheduling conflict?" which would seem to be a duplicate of the question that directly asks about this scheduling conflict (among others).

Comment: In any case, I have added another question to the duplicate list which directly asks about other time turners in relation to scheduling conflicts, so at the very least this would be a duplicate of that. cc @DheerajKumar

Comment: Though if the question is truly interested in whether classes could have only one student, independent of this scheduling conflict, I would have no problem reopening it (if edited to reflect that).

Comment: I hope that's what you mean Alex.

Answer (score 4):

### Probably not

Outside of OWL and NEWT years (fifth and seventh, respectively), the end of year exams are conducted by the regular teachers, presumably during the normally scheduled period for the class. We know that lessons are split by House, or taken at the same time by two Houses, but neither Transfiguration or Charms is a "shared" subject - Gryffindor attends lessons for both classes with only their House. Therefore, Hermione wouldn't need to be the only third year student taking Arithmancy and Ancient Runes to be the only one with a conflict, she would just need to be the only Gryffindor.

Unfortunately there's no explicit proof in the books that she's not the only student, unlike for Muggle Studies:

> "... And Ernie McMillan told me she's never missed a Muggle Studies class, but half of them are at the same time as Divination, and she's never missed one of them either!"
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter Twelve - The Patronus</sub>

However, it wouldn't make sense for Hogwarts to run the class for a single student, especially if that student wanted to take on such a heavy workload that she required a Time-Turner.

In terms of being the only Gryffindor, all other Gryffindor third years are shown in both Divination and Care of Magical Creatures lessons.

##### Divination

Neville:

> "... You, boy," she said suddenly to **Neville**, who almost toppled off his pouf. "Is your grandmother well?"
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter Six - Talons and Tea Leaves</sub>

Parvati:

> "... By the way, my dear," she shot suddenly at **Parvati Patil**, "beware a red-haired man."
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Lavender:

> "I wonder, dear," she said to **Lavender Brown**,who was nearest and shrank back in her chair, "if you could pass me the largest silver teapot?"
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Dean:

> "What is it, Professor?" said **Dean Thomas** at once.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Seamus:

> **Seamus Finnigan** was tilting his head from side to side.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

##### Care of Magical Creatures

Lavender:

> "Oooooooh!" squealed Lavender Brown, pointing toward the opposite side of the paddock.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Parvati:

> There was an intake of breath from behind him, and both Lavender and Parvati whispered, "Oooh, no, Harry, remember your tea leaves!"
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Neville:

> Neville ran repeatedly backward from his, which didn't seem to want to bend its knees.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Dean:

> "It was Malfoy's fault!" snapped Dean Thomas.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Seamus:

> "First pus and now this," muttered Seamus.
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter Thirteen - Mad-Eye Moody</sub>